# Up and Down icons in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl with multiple columns, all of which are able to be sorted by. I would like to add **up** and **down** icons so that it is clear which column is currently sorted upon, and in which direction; much like Windows Explorer. My thought was to add a solid up/down arrow to the column name. I tried using the extended ASCII chars 30/31; but instead of showing the arrows, I got boxes (the "character not found" character); and using the unicode version, I got a question mark instead of the character.

Any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the newer [CMFCListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983191.aspx) class or the [CMFCHeaderCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982730.aspx) class.  There, you can set the sort column and the sort direction.

Try

```
myListCtrl.SetSortColumn(nCol, bAscending);
```

or

```
CMFCHeaderCtrl &headerCntrl = myListCtrl.GetHeaderCtrl();
headerCntrl.SetSortColumn(nCol, bAscending);
```